# ANGULAR - ROUTER LINK A UN APARTADO ESPECIFICO DE LA PAGINA

Tags: javascript, angular, router, routing

mi problema es que estoy en un componente blog y en la navbar tengo un link productos que va a el componente main pero a un apartado llamado productos al hacer click en el link desde componente blog solo muestra el componente main y no se desplaza hacia abajo a productos. Alguna solución para esto? , en el componente main estoy usando el href para desplazarme pero desde otro componente no logro hacerlo funcionar..

**routing-module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component:MainComponent},
  {path: 'our-blog',component:OurBlogComponent},
  {path: 'about-us',component:AboutComponent},
  {path: 'product-detail',component:ProductDetailComponent},
  {path: 'shopping-cart',component:ShoppingCartComponent},
  {path: 'user-register',component:RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'user-login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'user-account',component:MyAccountComponent},
  {path: 'contact',component:ContactComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
  
];
```

Comment: podrias poner el código donde realizar la redireccion al componente?

Comment: Basicamente es esto en la navbar , <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a routerLink="/#products" class="nav-link " routerLinkActive="router-link-active" role="button" 
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Productos
                    </a>

                </li>

Comment: intenta quitando el # del routelink, ya que lo toma como un identificador de la pagina

Comment: no funciono :( , sigue cargando solamente el componente Main